# Evaluate a certain one-dimensional integral involving inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals, polylogarithm

Demonstrate that the integral of 
\begin{equation}
\cos (y) \left(\sqrt{4-\sin ^2(y)} \cos ^{-1}(\sin (y))+4 \cos (y) \csc ^{-1}(2 \csc
   (y))\right)
\end{equation}
over $y \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ equals
\begin{equation}
-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\pi ^2}{3}-2 \log ^2(2)+\frac{15
   \log (3)}{8} \approx 2.621207508030023088,
\end{equation}
where the polylogarithm function is employed. The origin of this assertion (in which I have confidence, but have yet been unable to formally demonstrate) is somewhat of a "long story", but I can expand upon its details.

Comment: An idea would be to use a substitution involving $u = \sin(y)$, since most of the expression is a function of that (and there is a $\cos(y)$ multiplying the whole thing)... I don't know if this will really help though.

Comment: It is interesting that after the substitution, we get an integrand of $\sqrt{4-u^2}\cos^{-1}(u) + 4\sqrt{1-u^2}\sin^{-1}{\frac{u}{2}}$. Denoting $f(u) = \cos^{-1}(u)$ ang $g(u) = 4\sin^{-1}(u/2)$, this is of the form $\frac{f}{g'}-\frac{g}{f'}$.

Comment: I Implemented the suggestion of Tob Ernack, performed the integration  over  $u \in [0,1]$ (having introduced the associated jacobian) and got precisely the result $-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\pi ^2}{3}-2 \log ^2(2)+\frac{15
   \log (3)}{8}$ indicated in the question.

Comment: I'd be curious to know how you proceeded from there, I wasn't able to do anything useful with the last expression I got (what is your associated jacobian)?

Comment: As some added background, the result $-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\pi ^2}{3}-2 \log ^2(2)+\frac{15
   \log (3)}{8}$ is equal to $\frac{\pi^2}{2}$ times the value $\tilde{\chi_1}(\frac{1}{2})$ given by eq. (9) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01410.pdf.

Comment: Tob Ernacak: The appropriate jacobian (introduced as a factor in the transformed integrand) was the derivative of $\sin ^{-1}(u)$ with respect to $u$, that is, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$. Thanks for the suggested transformation.

Comment: Tob Ernacak: The appropriate jacobian (introduced as a factor in the transformed integrand) was the derivative of $\sin ^{-1}(u)$ with respect to $u$, that is, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$. Thanks for the suggested transformation. It's now helped me to solve a more general problem, that is recreating the function  $\tilde{\chi_1}(\varepsilon)$ in eq. (9) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01410.pdf. (I needed an additional comment, as the time had expired for the immediate preceding one.)